# How to have my input value appear in all my html pages?

Tags: javascript

I am storing the username and password in an array(datas),,then after registering and logging in, I am only able to have the username appear in the login page.. How can i make the username appear in all of my html pages?Like storing it in a session variable so i could have the username in all of my other pages. Thank you!

```
<script>
let datas = [];
const addData = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let data = {
    username: document.getElementById('rusername').value,
    password: document.getElementById('rpassword').value
  }
  datas.push(data);
  document.forms[0].reset();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('register_button').addEventListener('click', addData);
});

function isUserValid(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var username = document.getElementById('lusername').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('lpassword').value;
  var found_user = datas.find(d => d.username === username && d.password === password);
  if (found_user) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('loguser')[0].innerHTML = found_user.username;
  }
}

document.getElementById("login_button").addEventListener("click", isUserValid);
</script>
<body>
  <div class="loguser">
    User
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="login_box">
      <div class="login_header">
        <img src="images/alimama.png" alt=""> <br> Login or Register!
      </div>

      <div id="login">
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <input id="lusername" type="text" name="lusername" placeholder="Username" required>
          <br>
          <input id="lpassword" type="password" name="lpassword" placeholder="Password">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" id="login_button" name="login_button" value="Login">
          <br>
          <a href="#" id="signup" class="signup">Need an account? Register here!</a>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="register">
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <input id="rusername" type="text" name="rusername" placeholder="Username" required>
          <br>
          <input id="rpassword" type="password" name="rpassword" placeholder="Password" required>
          <br>
          <input id="register_button" type="submit" name="register_button" value="Register">
          <br>
          <a href="#" id="signin" class="signin">Already have an account? Sign in here!</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: First, let me say that I sincerely hope this isn't protecting anything at all important, because an all client-side authentication scheme is trivially easy to crack. But assuming that's just a stand-in while you to work out some other details, like the one you ask about, the easiest way to display the username on each page is just to set a cookie with no expiration (so it will expire at the end of the browser session) and just read it from there on each page. But let me reiterate: DO NOT build a multi-page authentication system for actual release this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your browser's `localstorage` to store the values and retrieve them on other pages. Another option would be to use `cookies`, but I believe this would be a little more complicated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Here's the documentation that talks a little more about. I think this will help you =)

An important point is that this will be saved in the user's browser, if you need this data, I recommend using a database

Comment: @Linue Patorelli I put this inside the function but it doesnt allow me to take the variable outside the login page ```    var username = document.getElementById('lusername').value;
    var passwor =document.getElementById('lpassword').value;
    var found_user= datas.find(d => d.username === username && d.password === password);
    if (found_user) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('actualUserName', document.getElementById('lusername').value);
        var x = window.localStorage.getItem('actualUserName');
        document.getElementsByClassName('loguser')[0].innerHTML=x;
    }
}```

Comment: Put a ```console.log``` and see if this is actually being written to your localstorage, this is the easiest way to debug this

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage, is really simple. To set the value use this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('actualUserName', document.getElementById('lusername').value);
```

And to retrieve the value use this:

```
window.localStorage.getItem('actualUserName');
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage